# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nets' (TensorFlow)

Tags: python

Here is my error :

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg\object_detection\models\faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_feature_extractor.py", line 28, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nets'
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Lhja.png)

I have already change the python path but it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 2):

Maybe in a Windows environments, capital code couldn't check differently and differs from linux file system.

It has already BUILD file inside slim folder. Let's move BUILD to BUILD.old, then You can build slim package

```
c:\foo\bar\models\research> cd slim
c:\foo\bar\models\research\slim> move BUILD BUILD.old
c:\foo\bar\models\research\slim> python setup.py build
c:\foo\bar\models\research\slim> python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 1):

on windows 
in the C:\tensorflow\models\research\slim directory run
python setup.py build
python setup.py install

P.S
models/research/slim HAS ITS OWN setup.py!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
use the one specific for slim

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the `tensorflow/models/research/` and `slim` directories are added to PYTHONPATH (see the [installation instructions](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md#add-libraries-to-pythonpath)).

Either run the following

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
```

or add it to the end of your `~/.bashrc` so that it gets run automatically whenever you open a new terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy nets or slim folder to .....\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.5.egg

See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49724650/i-got-this-error-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-nets-tensorflow/53246620#53246620) solution works.

Answer (score 0):

I met same problem with you, since we are both in Windows Environment. What am I doing is that, I added little codes in the header of model_builder_test.py.

    `import sys
    sys.path.append("....../tutorial/models/research")
    sys.path.append("....../tutorial/models/research/slim")
    ......
    import tensorflow as tf
    from google.protobuf import text_format
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
    ......`