# I got this error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nets' (Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, module, path, installation

I was trying to run tensorflow model and I was using Python 3.6 with PyCharm (pip). I got this error:

```
Use the retry module or similar alternatives.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/erdogan/Desktop/tens/model/research/object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py", line 21, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 30, in <module>
    from object_detection.models import faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_feature_extractor as frcnn_inc_res
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/models/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_feature_extractor.py", line 28, in <module>
    from nets import inception_resnet_v2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nets'
```

I have used this:

```
Vural-MacBook-Pro:research erdogan$ export PYTHONPATH=/Users/erdogan/Desktop/tens/model/research/slim:$PYTHONPAT
```

But it did not work. I have also checked my path:

```
Vural-MacBook-Pro:research erdogan$ echo $PYTHONPATH
```

I got this:

```
/Users/erdogan/Desktop/tens/model/research/slim:
```

Comment: It looks like slim is not installed correctly. How did you install it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy the nets folder from slim to the installation directory. [Ref](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1842#issuecomment-377925135)